# call cmd start command can't run in R

Tags: r, windows-xp

I have tested many times .

```
#can run in R 
system("mplay32.exe  /play c:/m1.mp3")
system("mplay32.exe  /play c:\\m1.mp3")
#can run in XP CMD  
start /b mplay32.exe  /play c:\m1.mp3
#can not run in R
system("start /b mplay32.exe  /play c:\m1.mp3")
system("start /b mplay32.exe  /play c:\\m1.mp3")
system("start \/b mplay32.exe  /play c:\\m1.mp3")  
system("start \\/b mplay32.exe  /play c:\\m1.mp3")
```

how can i make `start /b mplay32.exe  /play c:\m1.mp3` run in R?

Comment: have you tried `shell()` instead of `system()` ?

Comment: `start` is a built-in command. It would work better with `cmd -k`